# How to verticaly put two buttons on top of each other so they split the height to equal 50% for each

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to do + and - buttons in Bootstrap so the + is on top of the - and they have 50% of the height of the full div each.

Something like this:

[image]

So I got the input and the `input-group-append` like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="input-group-append">
  <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        +
    </span>
  <span class="btn btn-outline-danger">
        -
    </span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this is the result:

[image]

As you can see they take the full block, each of them, taking too much space.
If they could be vertically combined that could make more place for other inputs.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use display: flex property

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
.input-group-append(or you can change the name but add it to parent div) {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

or just try changing `span` tags to `div`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Flex` property

```css
.input-group-append {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group-append">
  <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">
              +
            </span>
  <span class="btn btn-outline-danger">
              -
            </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `btn-group-vertical` to the parent div

```
<div class="input-group-append btn-group-vertical">
            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
              +
            </span>
            <span class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">
              -
            </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.input-group-append{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Use this css.